# cannot resolve unit name 'xxxxx' error while using class

Tags: delphi-xe8

I am creating a unit Stringy and its type is TStringy = Class. I am then trying to use this class in my form. So in other file.pas, I am trying to use it. While doing uses Stringy; on Stringy I am getting red line error 'Can not resolve unit name 'Stringy'

```
//TStringy.pas file:

unit Stringy;

interface

type
    TStringy = Class


//Code on form that is supposed to use it:

uses Stringy;
```

Comment: Looks like the compiler can't find the file. That means it's not in the project, and not on the search path, not in a visible package etc. We can't tell you how to fix this without knowing how you are planning to link it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my file name to Stringy.pas from TStringy.pas and issue resolved.